# Android Studio suddenly showing too many logs in Logcat

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, ide

For some reason my Android Studio 1.5.1 suddenly began showing a lot of logs than usual. I'm not sure if I clicked on or changed some settings accidentally, but now it's also showing logs if I lift the phone off the table.

How to get it back to only showing logs involving my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes by re-running the project or re-uploading the device with adb enabled, it will re-select the application in Android Monitor. Android Studio should takes by default the connected device and the debuggable application when launching it.

Be sure that **Enable ADB Integration** is checked in *Tools > Android*. Enable it should restart the Android Monitor and reselect your application in the Logcat window.

However if this isn't working, you have to use a specific filter as an app name or a package name **in the field above the logs console**. By using it, only the specific logs with the specific word will be displayed in Android Monitor.

**Without a filter** it displays all logs of the device:

[image: without-filter]

**With filter,** only the relevant logs with the keywords will show up (eg. I'm using "*keyboard*" word and only one line is showing):

[image: with-filter]

Comment: I just filtered it using my package name. But it's weird, I never had to do this before. I'm just not sure what I did to make it log up everything.

Comment: Sometimes restart adb server, by using kill-server and start-server, solves the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. Click Android Monitor at the bottom of a window
2. At the top of a subwindow you just opened there are two dropdowns.
3. Use the one on the right and select the application your app's process.

Comment: It's already set to "show only selected application", still it's shows me logs of stuff like "telephony signal strength"